# NHibernate remove item in collection not working

Tags: c#, nhibernate, collections

I'm a newbie in the NHibernate world.

Why this code works removing the territory from the collection:

```
Country country;

using (IUnitOfWork unit = UnitOfWork.Start())
{
    country = new Country();
    country.Name = "My country";

    Territory territory = new Territory();
    country.Territories.Add(territory);
    country.Territories.Remove(territory);
}
```

And this code is not working:

```
Country country;

using (IUnitOfWork unit = UnitOfWork.Start())
{
    country = _countries.GetById(1);

    Territory territory = new Territory();
    country.Territories.Add(territory);
    country.Territories.Remove(territory);
}
```

In the second code snippet, _countries is a repository. The country ID 1 exists in the database. The territory is added, but never removed...

Here's the mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="iCible.Artishows.Framework.ObjectDefinition"
                   namespace="iCible.Artishows.Framework.ObjectDefinition" >
  <class name="Country" >
    <id name="ID">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <set name="Territories" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" order-by="Name" sort="iCible.Artishows.Framework.ObjectDefinition.TerritoryComparer">
      <key column="COUNTRYID"/>
      <one-to-many class="Territory"/>
    </set>
    <property name="CreationDate" />
    <property name="EditionDate" />    
    <many-to-one class="User" name="CreationUser"/>
    <many-to-one class="User" name="EditionUser"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It was the inverse=true the issue. But both gave me good paths to solve my problems. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on the reason why, but I think it might be because of the `inverse="true"` part. The implication of having that, I think, is that it means the relationship is managed by the other side, i.e. from the Territory to the Country, so deleting the item from the `Country.Territories` may not work exactly as you expect.

What does your Territory mapping look like? - I assume it has a many-to-one reference to the Country parent?

Having said that, my NHibernate knowledge is still mostly at the level of "fiddle with the settings until it works like I want it to". But I'm pretty sure you'll be able to make it work by adjusting either the `inverse` attribute and/or the `cascade` option (i.e. try changing it to "all").

For what it's worth, most of our mappings that use one-to-many look like this, and I think we usually delete things in the same way as you showed:

```
<class name="Parent">
  <id name="ParentID">
  ...
  <map name="ChildCollection" cascade="all" inverse="true">
</class>

<class name="Child">
  ...
  <many-to-one name="Parent" column="ParentID" not-null="true">
</class>
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with a similar but different NHibernate problem with children not being deleted.  The answer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229469/nhibernate-parent-child-orphaned-records-with-web-service) might give you some insight, even if it's not exactly the same issue.